# Mutate a column with condition dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am new at R and i would like to know how to create a new column with conditionals values :(sorry if my english is bad ) .

I have a dataframe with 3 columns : ID of the person , Question and Answer .
I would like to add a column  'TEST' depending on the answer given by the persons .

For Exemple : If a person answered 'Paris' to the question 'where are you from' and 'No' to the question 'Do you like chocolate' the value asigned to the column 'TEST' should be 'A' .
But if he ansewerd 'Yes' and 'Paris' it should be 'B'.
You can see a full exemple in this picture :

[image]

Can someone please help me figure this out ... I've been trying to find a solution for 3 weeks now.

Comment: You'll first want to reshape your date from long to wide, using [`tidyr::pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#wider) and then use [`dplyr::case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html?q=case_when#ref-usage) to create the if else conditions for the TEST variable.

Comment: When you are posting a question, it is helpful to provide data in some other form than screenshot. In R the simplest way is to call `dput(your_data_object)` in the console and then copypaste the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Question, 
    values_from = Answer) %>%
  mutate(Test = ifelse(`Where are you from?` == "Paris" & `Do you like chocolate?` == "No",
                       "A",
                       ifelse(`Where are you from?` == "Paris" & `Do you like chocolate?` == "Yes",
                              "B",
                              "C")))
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID `Where are you from?` `Do you like chocolate?` Test 
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>                    <chr>
1   111 Paris                 Yes                      B    
2   222 Paris                 No                       A    
3   333 DC                    Yes                      C
```

If you want to have the dataframe in its original format, add `pivot_longer`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Question, 
    values_from = Answer) %>%
  mutate(Test = ifelse(`Where are you from?` == "Paris" & `Do you like chocolate?` == "No",
                       "A",
                       ifelse(`Where are you from?` == "Paris" & `Do you like chocolate?` == "Yes",
                              "B",
                              "C"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3,
               names_to = "Question")
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID Test  Question               value
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>                  <chr>
1   111 B     Where are you from?    Paris
2   111 B     Do you like chocolate? Yes  
3   222 A     Where are you from?    Paris
4   222 A     Do you like chocolate? No   
5   333 C     Where are you from?    DC   
6   333 C     Do you like chocolate? Yes
```